# How can I set audio balance of a soundcard programmatically?

Tags: c#, audio

How can I set the balance of a soundcard with C#.Net?

What would be the most common way? Do I need Interop?

Comment: Can you be more descriptive as to what you mean by balance?  Are you talking about left and right channels?

Comment: right. I'd like to control the two channels according the volume of each

Answer (score 0):

You will first need a framework for working with your sound card. Managed Direct X. It includes Direct Sound, which will let you control your sound card with a comfortable level of abstraction.

You can find a tutorial on Managed Direct X here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/mdx_tutorial1.aspx

Comment: directx is what I'm currently using in my app - would be a good solution to use it also therefore. unfortunately I cannot find a proper method that would set the soundlevel of a channel or the balance

Comment: Also take a look at here: http://gpwiki.org/index.php/VBNET:DirectSound

Search for "Pan". I think these should get you in the right direction

Comment: I don't want to control how sound is played. I'd like to control on what level the incoming sound (line-in) is.